# Using findstr in if in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I tried last week to figure out how an if works in a batch file and no that it should work it just doesn't. I have no idea what's wrong or how to solve the problem since I may have made an error with the if or that I'm missing out on something important.

```
findstr /C:"Firefox" C:\TestIffile.txt
pause
IF (findstr /C:"Firefox" C:\TestIffile.txt) (
ECHO Firefox > C:\TestIffileResult.txt
) ELSE (
ECHO no Firfox
)
```

The first findstr works fine and gives me this result. `DisplayName    REG_SZ    Mozilla Firefox 58.0.2 (x64 en-GB)` which is perfectly fine. The second findstr gives me something like "Firefox was unintended". I've been told that the if would handle the findstr command with a true or false signal but if so why won't it work properly? Thank you in advance.

Btw it's not to find the exe of the program but to save a lot of work by filtering out unwanted lines in my datafiles.

Comment: `if <command> ...` doesn't work in Batch. See `if /?`. What you've been told might work for most programming languages, but definitively not for Batch.

Comment: I would also add that you could use `Reg Query` on the registry key and use `/F "Firefox" /D`, `Find` or `FindStr` directly without writing it to a file, then filtering the file!

Comment: @Stephan Sometimes it doesn't help to tell someone to see if /? since you can see it doesn't work properly with me. I actually just needed a working example to get an idea on how to use it. Well Compo helped me. Thanks again ;D

Comment: @M.Stephen (no offense intended; most people don't bother to read the help). If /?` states the following three possibilities: `IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command`, `IF [NOT] string1==string2 command` and `IF [NOT] EXIST filename command`. There is no `IF [NOT] command command`.

Comment: perhaps I haven't read through it with a comb but I must also say that I haven't really understood it then :C
Would prefer to use Linux but there is only a 1% of computers with linux in my company so I've got no real choice there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your provided search term, this is how I'd structure it using `Find`:

```bat
(Find /I "Firefox"<"C:\TestIfFile.txt" >Nul && (Echo Firefox
) || Echo No Firefox)> C:\TestIffileResult.txt
```

…and using `FindStr`:

```bat
(FindStr /IC:"Firefox" "C:\TestIfFile.txt" >Nul && (Echo Firefox
) || Echo No Firefox)> C:\TestIffileResult.txt
```

*In either case I would probably first put in a condition based on the existence or otherwise of `C:\TestIfFile.txt`.*

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "C:\TestIfFile.txt" Exit /B
```

*I would also note that most Windows systems by default prevent writing to a file in the root of the system drive, without administrative privileges.*

Comment: the existence of that file will be assured since I will create it beforehand. I actually just need help with one little bit of the program or else I would have writen please someone write me a tool which does this and this and this. :D haha
No I just needed some examples on how to add something like an if.

Comment: ...and, did you consider that my examples helped?

Comment: sorry but I haven't found the time to try them yet but I will let you of course know and mark this as helpful and solved. So yeah I will let you know asap

Comment: Thanks dude. This is exactly what I needed. Works perfectly